# goto-file in Emacs

Tags: emacs

Is there a substitute in emacs for the vi `gf` command?
I mean to open the file which is under the cursor right now, if a real file name is in fact there.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You want the `find-file-at-point` function (which is also aliased to `ffap`).  It's not bound to a key by default, but you can use

```
M-x ffap
```

Or, you can put in your `.emacs` file:

```
(ffap-bindings)
```

This will replace many of the normal `find-file` key bindings (like `C-x C-f`) with `ffap`-based versions.  See the commentary in `ffap.el` for details.

Comment: thanks cjm! nice emacs howto of the day!
I can open another batch file called from my main batch file.
I guest it must be easily work for C/C++ include.
Altough, I don't think it can open the right Java Class :)

Comment: i have not tested it, and i know, that this discussion is pretty old, but i just found this: `You can open a Java source file or directory from the import statement in Java. The location of the source must be known to work via ffap-java/source-directories. The source should be either a directory name that contains the sources, or a jar archive name that contains the sources. Download the source here. – cinsk` (Source: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FindFileAtPoint)

Comment: This instead opens a dialog for me with `helm-mode-find-file-at-point`.

Answer (score 8):

Thanks, it works quite well but somehow the vi (gf) version is
still somewhat smarter. I think it looks at some path variable for search paths.

I made something which is needlessly complicated but works for me (only in linux).
It uses the "locate" command to search for the path under the cursor.
I guess it could be made smarter by searching the relative path to the current file first.
sorry for my bad elisp skills...It can probably be achieved in a much nicer way.

put in your .emacs, then use with M-x goto-file

```
(defun shell-command-to-string (command)
  "Execute shell command COMMAND and return its output as a string."
  (with-output-to-string
    (with-current-buffer standard-output
      (call-process shell-file-name nil t nil shell-command-switch command))))

(defun goto-file ()
  "open file under cursor"
  (interactive)
  (find-file (shell-command-to-string (concat "locate " (current-word) "|head -c -1" )) ))
```

Comment: My Emacs already has shell-command-to-string defined in simple.el