# emacs: open the file which my current cursor position points to

Tags: emacs, cursor

I am wondering does emacs have a command that opens the file where the cursor points to.
eg: I have a ASCII file with the following text:

```
source ../scripts/setup.tcl
```

I would like to have a command that opens the file `../scripts/setup.tcl` when my current cursor position is on one of the characters of the file.

Comment: Try M-x ffap command.

Comment: There's a more detailed answer here.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/259354/goto-file-in-emacs

Answer (score 1):

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-f") 'ffap)
```